# How to delete a Macro using phpword?

Tags: php, libraries, phpword

I am using phpword to manipulate Word Documents. I am currently working with the templateProcessor class.

My template has some macros associated with variables which may receive blank strings. This is the code behind it:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    ${"objetivo$i"} = $data["objetivo$i"];
}

$valoresObjetivos = [
    'objetivo1' => $objetivo1,
    'objetivo2' => $objetivo2,
    'objetivo3' => $objetivo3,
    'objetivo4' => $objetivo4,
    'objetivo5' => $objetivo5,
    'objetivo6' => $objetivo6,
    'objetivo7' => $objetivo7,
    'objetivo8' => $objetivo8,
    'objetivo9' => $objetivo9,
    'objetivo10' => $objetivo10,
];

// Add char • before variable value
$valoresObjetivos = array_map(function ($valor) {
    return ($valor !== '') ? "• $valor" : $valor;
}, $valoresObjetivos);

// Delete empty variables
$valoresObjetivos = array_map(function ($valor) {
    return ($valor === '') ? "" : $valor;
}, $valoresObjetivos);

$templateProcessor->setValues($valoresObjetivos);
```

The problem is i'm dealing with blank lines in my word document.
The first image is the template and the second image is the final document.
[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiPK3.png)
[final document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0fbb.png).
I'd like to remove those blank lines. Is there a way I can do it using phpWord?

Thank you very much!

Tried to remove blank linkes.
Were expecting to be successfull.
I wasn't successfull.